# A problem about voting on a numeric value

Tags: calculus, average, economics, voting-theory

Let $w = f(v)$ where $f$ is a strictly increasing continuous function $[0;+\infty)\to [0;1)$. Let $A(w_1,\dots,w_n)$ be some average. Then we want $f^{-1}(A(f(cv_1),\dots,f(cv_n))) = cf^{-1}(A(f(v_1),\dots,f(v_n)))$ for every positive constant $c$.

Is this possible for some $f$ and $A$? Which one?

The question originated from [this real world economical problem](https://forum.aragon.org/t/idea-voting-on-a-numeric-value/1525).

In a "good" solution the value $f^{-1}(A(f(v_1),\dots,f(v_n)))$ of should not go infinite when one of the values $v_k$ tends to plus infinity.

Comment: This problem has a "bad" solution that does not solve the real issue: Take $B$ any average (arithmetic, geometric, etc.) and let $A(w_1,\dots,w_n) = f(B(f^{-1}(w_1),\dots,f^{-1}(w_n)))$. It is bad because the proposed conversion to the range $[0;1)$ loses sense: it leads to the same result as just taking an average of values $v_1$, ..., $v_n$ that does not solve the real economical problem.

Comment: I've added to the question a property a good solution should have.

Comment: It seems that $A$ cannot be the arithmetic average, because otherwise it seems that $f$ must be a linear function, what is obviously impossible. Correct?

Comment: Somehow related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3452492/4876

Comment: A more interesting conjecture for the purpose to solve the same real-world problem I am trying to solve in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3452518/4876