# Conjecture about generalized means

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, average, conjectures

**Conjecture** Every continuous function $f(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ of $n$ arguments such that it lies in the closed interval $[\min(v_{1},\dots ,v_{n});\max(v_{1},\dots ,v_{n})]$, is symmetric for all permutations of arguments, and is [homogeneous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function) (with the degree $1$) necessarily is a [generalized mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean).

Help me to prove or disprove (with a counterexample) this conjecture. Is it a known result?

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3452518/4876

Comment: What about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_mean?