# Does "finite average" exist?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, average, conjectures

I will call an *average* any continuous function $f(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ of $n$ arguments such that it lies in the closed interval $[\min(v_{1},\dots ,v_{n});\max(v_{1},\dots ,v_{n})]$, is symmetric for all permutations of arguments, and is [homogeneous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function) with the degree $1$.

Question: Can an average *not* to tend to infinity when one of the arguments tends to infinity and the rest arguments are fixed nonnegative reals? (We can assume $n\geq 2$.)

My original question had a trivial solution $\min(v_{1},\dots ,v_{n})$, so let's add an additional requirement: our average *not* to tend to zero when one of the arguments tends to zero and the rest arguments are fixed positive reals? (We can assume $n\geq 2$.)

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3452492/4876

Comment: The given answer (below) solves your original question. Your appended question can be solved by the second-smallest minimum (assuming $n\geq 3$).

Comment: @Michael To exclude such silly things as second largest minimum, we may require also that the function $f$ is $C^p$-smooth (e.g. for $p=1$ or $p=\infty$) for each argument. It is now a different question. Should I edit my original question or ask a new one?

Comment: Alternatively, you could take a traditional average over only the $n-1$ smallest values (assuming $n\geq3$). [Edit: I typed this at same time as last comment: this is not smooth. I suggest giving best answer to the person below, then make new question.]

Comment: @Michael I should have asked also for a stronger requirement: $f$ does not tend to infinity when all arguments except one tend to infinity. This condition would rule out the answer from your last comment.

Comment: Less trivial modification of the question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3452562/4876

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure this matches your needs, but $f(v_1,...,v_n)=\min(v_1,...,v_n)$ might obey all your requirements. It is homogeneous of degree 1, symmetric in all permutation of arguments, and if only one argument goes to infinity, it will not change it's value. Also, it lies in the closed interval you want.

Comment: Are there any other solutions except for $\min$?

Comment: I added an additional requirement to the question to eliminate this trivial answer. Please consider my question again.

Comment: You somehow need to eliminate the maximum value, and still be homogeneous with degree 1. Some kind of median would work, or some weighted mean that excludes at least the maximum value. My first thought was something like $\arctan$ function, but that is not homogeneous.

Answer (score 1):

For $k=1,2,...,n$ define $m_k=\min_{i\neq k}\{v_i\}$ and $f(v_1,...,v_n)=\max_{k=1,...,n}\{m_k\}$. This can be generalized to exclude the first $l$ minima, which will alow $f$ to not go to zero, as the entries $v_1, ..., v_l\to 0$.