# Does “smooth finite average” exist?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, average, conjectures, smooth-functions

*([That question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3452518/4876) was answered. I realized I asked a wrong question. So here is a modified question.)*

I will call an *average* any continuous function $f(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ of $n$ arguments such that it lies in the closed interval $[\min(v_{1},\dots ,v_{n});\max(v_{1},\dots ,v_{n})]$, is symmetric for all permutations of arguments, and is [homogeneous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3452518/4876) with the degree $1$.

Question: Can an average provided the below additional requirements (I ask for the case if all of them are required but also for milder cases of just a part of these requirements) *not* to tend to infinity when one of the arguments tends to infinity and the rest arguments are fixed nonnegative reals? (We can assume $n\geq 2$.)

- Our average does not tend to infinity when all arguments except one tend to infinity.
- Our average is $C^1$-smooth in every argument (maybe except the argument(s) value equal to zero).
- Our average is $C^\infty$-smooth in every argument (maybe except the argument(s) value equal to zero).

Comment: I think you have mixed up the two links in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a weighted average where the weight of each argument decreases homogeneously as the argument tends to infinity. For example, if you choose the weight of an argument $v_i$ to be $w(v_i)=v_i^{-2}$, you get
$$f(v_1,\dots,v_n)=\frac{v_1^{-1}+\dots+v_n^{-1}}{v_1^{-2}+\dots+v_n^{-2}}.$$

In fact, this formula remains bounded when up to $n-1$ values tend to infinity.

---

If you want something that behaves more like the traditional average, and in particular doesn't have $f(v_1,\dots,v_n)\to0$ when any $v_i\to0$, you can try
$$f(v_1,\dots,v_n)=\frac{v_1^2(v_2+\dots+v_n)+\dots+v_n^2(v_1+\dots+v_{n-1})}{(v_1^2+\dots+v_n^2)(n-1)}.$$
This is the weighted average, with weights $v_i^2$, of each average where one argument $v_i$ excluded.

Compared to the previous formula, this one only remains bounded if at most one argument tends to infinity.

Comment: Is this function increasing in every argument?

Comment: I've realized that I need also the additional requirement that $f$ does not tend to zero when one of the arguments tends to zero (and the rest arguments are non-zero). Does your function conform to this additional requirement?

Comment: It seems that your function is not homogeneous! It was one of my requirements in the question.

Comment: 1. If the $v_i$ are nonnegative then I think yes. 2. No. 3. It is homogeneous if $w$ is homogeneous.

Comment: Your new requirement is impossible when $n=2$. Consider $v_1=1,v_2=x$. By your old requirement, when $x\to\infty$ you want $f(1,x)\to c<\infty$. By homogeneity, $f(1/x,1)=1/xf(1,x)\to c/x\to 0$. So as $1/x\to0$ you must have $f(1/x,1)\to0$, contradicting your new requirement. That said, it may be possible to satisfy both requirements as long as $n>2$.

Comment: It seems you misunderstand. I require homogenuity of degree $1$, your contradiction example is for homogenuity of degree $-1$. Or it is me who misunderstands?

Comment: $f(1/x,1)=f(\alpha\cdot1,\alpha x)=\alpha f(1,x)$ where $\alpha=1/x$.

Comment: It seems that you misunderstand what is homogeneous. It should be true for _all_ $\alpha$, not only for $\alpha=1/x$! Or it is me who misunderstands something?

Comment: I give up. $\quad$

Comment: Ok, I will try again. What I am showing is that if you want degree-1 homogeneity, you cannot both have $f(x,1)\not\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$ and also have $f(1,y)\not\to0$ as $y\to0$.

Comment: It seems I didn't understand you because you have a typo: You wrote "That said, it may be possible to satisfy both requirements". As I now understand it should be "That said, it may be _not_ possible to satisfy both requirements".

Comment: "That said..." means "Even though I have said that, nevertheless...". In particular, what I wrote meant "Even though I have showed that it is impossible for $n=2$, it *may still be possible* to satisfy both requirements when $n>2$".

Comment: You may like my updated answer.